# remove css property set for radio btutton inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 65%;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  background: #AAA;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-weight: 400
}

.chngamt-head,
.toggle-label:active {
  font-weight: 700
}

.toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .87);
  text-align: center
}

.toggle-label-off {
  padding-left: 2px
}

.stylechngbut,
.styleinpamt {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 15px
}

.toggle-input {
  display: none
}

.toggle-input:checked+.toggle-label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .15s ease-out;
  transition: .15s ease-out
}

.toggle-input:checked+.toggle-label-on~.toggle-selection {
  left: 50%
}

.toggle-selection {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 49%;
  height: 26px;
  background: #65bd63;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9dd993, #65bd63);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-transition: left .15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left .15s ease-out;
  transition: left .15s ease-out
}

.toggle-blue .toggle-selection {
  background: #FCCD17;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff3b2, #fccd17);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff3b2, #fccd17);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff3b2, #fccd17);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff3b2, #fccd17)
}

.toggle-yellow .toggle-selection {
  background: #c4bb61;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e0dd94, #c4bb61);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e0dd94, #c4bb61);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e0dd94, #c4bb61);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e0dd94, #c4bb61)
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
[type="radio"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* checkbox aspect */

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label::before,
[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
  content: "";
  height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 45px;
}


/* checked mark aspect */

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  color: #ffffff;
  content: "✔";
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 14px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}


/* checked mark aspect changes */

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* disabled checkbox */

[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="radio"]:disabled:checked+label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:disabled:checked+label:after {
  color: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:disabled+label {
  color: #aaa;
}


/* accessibility */

[type="radio"]:checked:focus+label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked):focus+label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}


/* hover style just for information */

label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: #FFDF66;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle toggle-blue reset-this">

  <input type="radio" class="toggle-input " name="SchemeType" value="R" id="LStoggle" checked />
  <label for="LStoggle" class="toggle-label toggle-label-off">
    Male
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="SchemeType" value="D" id="SIPtoggle" />
  <label for="SIPtoggle" class="toggle-label toggle-label-on">
    female
  </label>
  <span class="toggle-selection"></span>
</div>
```

i am using  css property [type="radio"] for radio button outside class **toggle** div  but radio button inside  class **toggle** should not use  css property [type="radio"] it should  remove the css property set for radio button outside **class toggle** div i used css combinator but its not working i want following output  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvsf9kc1/4/) any help will be appreciated

Comment: just use the fiddle code.

Comment: in jsfiddle i am not using  [type="radio"] property on real page i am using [type="radio"] css property jsfiddle just for refrence

Comment: @user6885473 you're using input radio in fiddle. check it. However, If I will code this. I'll use javascript. It will be easy as ABC.

Comment: So you want input[type=radio] property and use the same design?

Comment: i want radio button inside the <div class="toggle toggle-blue reset-this"> should not use any css property set in css with respect to [type="radio"]